# Unable to read SMS for iOS in ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

We have an Ionic app in which we need to read an SMS with a validation code that the user will receive when registering into the app.
We are using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sms-receive) plugin which works perfectly in Android. But does not work on IOS it seems like.
I’ve also seen this Native plugin but it does not support reading SMS I don’t think.

The problem is when building the app for ios it won't read the SMS, well actually it doesn’t even enter the callback.
From what I have read it does not feel possible, also there is not much info about this subject on the internets!
My questions are:

- Is it something to do with ios permissions? If so, any help on this
  would be nice!
- Does anybody know of a way of accomplishing this for IOS?